# Adding google translate to react project

Tags: reactjs, translate

i am trying to add google translate to my project .I tried to add it in useEffect

```
const googleTranslateElementInit = () => {
    new window.google.translate.TranslateElement(
      {
        pageLanguage: "en",
        autoDisplay: false
      },
      "google_translate_element"
    );
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    var addScript = document.createElement("script");
    addScript.setAttribute(
      "src",
      "//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"
    );
    document.body.appendChild(addScript);
    window.googleTranslateElementInit = googleTranslateElementInit;
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    </>
  );
```

and react still rendering it two times in screen. I also tried to put it to index.html but when i do that div keeps disappearing when i resize to screen or change the mobile view and sometimes when i just start the project.  When it happens i have to refresh the page to bring it back . I jsut want to see a permanent div on my screen :P . I will be happy if you can help with that.

Comment: also gettin script error when i add it with useEffect